# SQL Server Search in column where contains part of a text

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, search

So, I'm making a program in WindowsForm with C# and I have a Search Box, where the user can search a list of clients. 
What I want to do is: when the user hits 'Search', select from the clients table all the lines that contains, in the name column, the text that the user had written. Like:

I have Alan and Mark registred in the clients table, and the user writes 'a' in the searchbox, it has to bring Alan and Mark, because they have the letter 'a' in their name.

Comment: Well this seems a good plan. Did you start to write the code for accomplish it? Remember that you don't come here to ask people writing code for you. Read the [help] before posting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the code here because all i want is actually the SQL code, not the c#/winform code.

Comment: I have tried the `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE text`
But the text had to be 'Alan' or 'Mark', nor just a letter or part of the name.

I also tried `CONTAINS`, but it had the same effect :/

Comment: Check the [docs about the LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) statement in Sql-Server. You will notice that it supports wild-card characters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple like will solve your problem:

```
Select * from yourtable where [name] like '%a%'
```

Comment: Can I use Parameters in it? I'm trying, but it brings me nothing back. When I try with `'%a%'`, it works normal.

Comment: Yes @AlanFelipe  and google will rerun a ton of examples mate! Good luck!!

Comment: Have you heard of SQL Injection attacks?

Answer (score 1):

```
string userInput = searchTextBox.Text; 
string query = "select* from client where name like" + '%' + userInput + '%';
```

- Now you can use that query.

[EDIT FOR SECURITY]

```
cmd.CommandText = "select* from client where name like @Name;";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + userInput + "%");
```

Comment: Have you heard of SQL Injection attacks?

Comment: You're giving the community the answer, not just the OP. If you're suggesting a solution with such a big security issue you should point it out in your answer.